# Can I use the splashScreenImage to all my app pages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, splash-screen

I'm writing an application for wp7 with several pages, and i want to the splash screen image at the load of every page i have in the app - so the user would figure out he needs to wait a few seconds.
The default splash screen image is fine for me, but i don't know how to do it.
thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your own splashscreen dont need to use the default

Use the Loading method for the page which should be located on a panel on the left side of Visual Studio's Screen

Comment: Hi KPath001 i cant find the loading method you have maintained

Comment: There should be a panel on the top left side along with the toolbox panel for the page as a whole if you use that and click events on the properties you will find a loading event

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by loading the SplashScreen Image on load of every page for some predefined time. And meanwhile other tasks can be done on Background threads (if they are not related to UI).

Also if you want to show a loader to User, you can create a Grid with some Background (semi transparent) and a Progress Bar on it. You can set its Visisbility true before any process which will take time and then hide it after process ends and Application is ready for user..